# Reading Old Values From SharedPreferences File X-Application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating and writing to a SharedPreferences file to store configuration information from one application like so:

```
public void setCustomAsync (. . . final Context context . . .) {
    if (prefs == null || editor == null) {
        prefs  = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }
    editor.putString("Custom", info); // This may be changing a previously set value
    editor.apply();

    // Creating backups of the preferences file
    execCommand(copyToBackup);
    execCommand(mainFixPerm);
    execCommand(bakFixPerm);
    activity.finish();
}

public void execCommand (String[] arg0) {
    try {
    final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arg0);
    final int retval = pr.waitFor();
    if (retval != 0) { Log.d("ERROR:", String.valueOf(retval)); }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

From another application I am reading that information:

```
private static String getCustom (final Context appContext) throws NameNotFoundException {
    context = appContext.createPackageContext("com.example.settings", 0);
    prefs   = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    return prefs.getString("Custom", EMPTY);
}
```

My problem is not that I cannot get the file, but that **the values are not up-to-date when being read by the second application**.

After debugging the first application I can see that saving new configurations to the file is working properly, but only when the second application is restarted does it show the updated configuration. Otherwise it keeps reading the old values.

Now I see when reading about SharedPreferences [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) that

> "Objects that are returned from the various get methods must be treated as immutable by the application."

But every time I am reading values from the file in the second application I restate prefs, so I am pulling it in as something new correct? I am not sure if that is the issue and how to get around that aspect.

Thank you!

NOTE: The code I have posted is paraphrased from my actual application, keeping only the parts relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS on top of the other two requirements. Which is only available in newer APIs.